# Checking validity of input - Setter function

Tags: c++, class, setter, getter-setter

This is an exercise for a university project, currently studying object oriented programming, I am rather new at this.

I have a class `Publication` with the properties `Headline` and `Text`.
This is the code for the class (the header file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

class publication
{
    private:
        string headline,text;
    public:
        publication(); //constructor

        void set_headline(string const new_headline);
        void set_text(string const new_text);

        string get_headline();
        string get_text();

        void print();
}
```

And this is the implementation (.cpp file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "publication.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

publication::publication()
{
    publication.headline="";
    publication.text="";
}

void publication::set_headline(string const new_headline)
{
    publication.headline=new_headline; //any input is valid
}

void publication::set_text(string const new_text)
{
    publication.text=new_text; //any input is valid
}

string publication::get_headline()
{
    return publication.headline;
}

string publication::get_text()
{
    return publication.text;
}
```

I don't see any issues so far, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is my problem:

I need to define a new class called `Article`. An `Article` is a type of `Publication`, as such it inherits from it, but it also has a unique field of its own called `Author`.

Here is the code for `Article` class (header file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "publication.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

class article: public publication
{
    private:
        string author;
    public:
        article();

        void set_author(string const new_author);

        string get_author();
}
```

And this is the implementation (.cpp file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "article.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

article::article()
{
    article.author="";
    article.set_headline("");
    article.set_text("");
}

void article::set_author(string const new_author)
{
    article.author=new_author;
}

string article::get_author()
{
    return article.author;
}
```

Here is my issue:

In the `set_author` method I want to check that the input is valid. As far as I know, there is no person named `123` or a person named `Bob%^!@`. Is there a way to check if a string contains characters that aren't letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let me point out a few issues that I've spotted.

In your class constructors and setters, you do not use a dot-separator the assign new values to the member data.

Where you have `publication.headline="";`, you can just do `headline = "";`. This applies to all cases where your using member data within its own class, and as such it applies to your `article` class as well.

Second, in your `article` class. You were correct in the way you setup your .h file for inheritance; however, in your .cpp for the constructor you must extend the `publication` constructor onto the `article` constructor like so...

```
article::article() : publication()
{
    ....
}
```

The `: publication()` is a call to the `super` class's constructor and without it, the `headline` and `text` data members won't be initialized.

Also its common practice for `const` variables to be written in this style: `const <data-type> <variable-name>`, so where you have `string const new_author` or anything of the sort, just switch to `const string new_author`.

Now, as for validating your input the way you're talking about, you can use two different methods that I know of off the top of my head. One is using the `isalpha()` method, and the other is using the `ASCII` table to check the values of each character.

[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) Method... simple iterator through each character and check if the values are between 65 and 90 or 97 and 122... (refer to [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) table for help). For this example I'll use a variable called `name` for the input string variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
{
    if ((int(name[i]) >= 65 && int(name[i]) <= 90) 
         || (int(name[i]) >= 97 && int(name[i]) <= 122))
    {
        ...the character is A-Z or a-z...
    }
}
```

The function method...

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
{
    if (!(isalpha(name[i])))
    {
        ...the character is only A-Z or a-z...
    }
}
```

I hope this helped! Happy programming!